# How to remove identical values ​on 2 array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to remove the same values from two tables such as:

```
var array1 = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]
var array2 = ["3", "4", "5"]
```

And I want to result :

```
var result = ["1", "2"]
```

Comment: please share code what you have tried so far

Comment: @Antonin_04 what if `array2 = ["3", "4", "5","6"]`

Comment: Show your best attempt so far and explain what went wrong with it (errors, unexpected results, etc.). Then we can help you.

Comment: @NagaSaiA
I've already tried but i don't have found

Comment: @Antonin_04 what if  array1 = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "5"]?

Comment: @Antonin_04 This is a Q&A site not a code-generation service. Ideally, we want to help you improve readers understanding of the problem, not just provide a copy/paste solution. Even if your attempt didn't work or didn't even compile, please show your work, so we can point out *where* you went wrong for your benefit as well as for future readers that may be experiencing similar issues. Also, as other commenters have pointed out, the requirements are rather vague on specific edge cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `filter()` and `includes()` and `concat()`. It will work for both arrays

```js
var array1 = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]
var array2 = ["3", "4", "5","6"]

let result = array1.filter(x => !array2.includes(x)).concat(array2.filter(x => !array1.includes(x)))
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

`array1
    .concat(array2)
    .filter((v, i, a) => a.indexOf(v) === i)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `filter` and `include`

```
    var array1 = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]
    var array2 = ["3", "4", "5"]

    array1.filter((a) => { return !array2.includes(a)});
```

Comment: pay attention at the support for IE ;)

Answer (score 0):

Use `filter` and invert the return from `includes`:

```js
var array1 = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]
var array2 = ["3", "4", "5"]
var result = array1.filter(e => !array2.includes(e));
console.log(result);
```